# Which site do I ask about a home network problem with server and vpn?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I keep getting told I'm in the wrong place :)

I'm having odd troubles with my home network since I added a media server which uses a VPN to the outside world.  SOME (not all) internal network traffic is affected unless I disable the VPN.  I'm lost.  I thought Server Fault made sense, but I see people getting lambasted for not being a professional.  My new guess is Super User... but figured I'd ask here first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The help center for Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) states it is suitable to ask "personal and home computer networking" related questions on it, so you should be good to go on there.

To cross it *off* the list of contenders (and for completeness), there's also http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com; but that's also for professional outfits only.

Answer (score 0):

Super User is so bloated with categories of questions, that it's nearly hopeless to illicit a good answer about anything that is remotely related to (so-called) "home networking", and Network Engineering is so "professional" that layman questions get booted almost immediately.  The problem is that many "home" users are (in reality) not quite amateurs (using servers, VPNs, custom router firmwares, etc.) and not operating in the "professional" (ie: service provider networks) realm.  It leaves a huge vacuum of dead-zones that is extremely frustrating.  There really should be a "Home Networking" site.

Decided to try and get a StackExchange site going. If you've ever struggled with "home" networking, or you have a modicum of expertise in managing and setting up Home/Small Office (SOHO) networks, please help me support this.

Hers the link to [Small Office / Home (SOHO) Networking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119149/small-office-home-office-soho-networking).  Please sign up contribute and share the link with other's who need help or who can provide guidance.

Comment: You can propose one on [area51.se].

Comment: Sure did.  Thanks @Glorfindel